# Watch Connectivity sendMessageData max size of data

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos, watchconnectivity, wcsession

I use WCSession sendMessageData to transfer images across from my iPhone to my watch. Everything works fine if the images are smaller. When they get bigger the messaging fails with

> Message reply failed.

I assume there is a maximum size for data sent with sendMessageData and it should be around ~70kb but I can´t find any piece of documentation on this. Can anybody help me out and maybe tell me if I can influence the maximum size of the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The transferFile API seems like a much better fit for this, and transfers the contents just as fast as messages from my experience

Comment: I totally agree that transferFile is way better for transferring files like images. The disadvantage of transferFile though is that I can not precisely set the moment when the file is transferred. I wanted to use sendMessageData to request an image immediately.